# Display Mode in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It's mentioned somewhere that when the browser is a Mobile one, ASP.NET MVC4 will request _Layout.Mobile.cshtml. This is not the case and not happening.

Any configuration needed to be done to enable this feature?

Answer (score 4):

According to ASP.NET Team(http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes):

> If your Views\Shared folder contains both the _Layout.cshtml and
>   _Layout.mobile.cshtml templates, by default the application will use _Layout.mobile.cshtml during requests from mobile browsers and _Layout.cshtml during other requests.

If you have those files then maybe the problem is the mobile engine is not being detected correctly, may you tell us if you upgraded a MVC 3 project to MVC 4 or created a new MVC 4 project? If the first, I recommend you to try to create a new MVC 4 project and see if the problem still happens, if it does maybe your MVC 4 installation is somewhat corrupt...

**EDIT:**
You need to to copy the Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml to Views\Shared_Layout.Mobile.cshtml. As it appears to be not added automatically.

Comment: See my tutorial ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Comment: I'm running through that tutorial now and running into the issue that the iPhone (through iOS Simulator on Mac OS X) is being detected (iPad is not) and my physical Android phone (Standard browser on 2.3.3) is NOT detected.  Is this "Mobile" functionality just magic we will have to override at some point?  This concerns me for any production use that it won't effectively identify mobile browsers. :-/

Comment: Did some searching and added in regex code from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and now android detection is working correctly.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same issue, found the solution here  http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/26/51Degrees-mobi-and-MVC4.aspx

Cheers,

Comment: that's exactly what i posted before:)

Comment: I've gave this answer on Feb 2012, you've update your answer in March 2013 to include the link

Answer (score 1):

First... make sure you have an MVC4 project - either clean from the template, or properly followed Microsoft's upgrade instructions.

As with other versions of MVC, the project structure works by convention and typically the views have to be in particular folders - for example, Views for your FoodController are expected to be in `Views -> Food` and templates are expected to be in the `Views -> Shared` folder.

Assuming `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml` is in the Shared Views folder, it may be case sensitive - `_Layout.mobile.cshtml` though I doubt it.

Have you used Fiddler to examine the Request sent (headers and UA) and the Response coming back?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, in my case, i have upgrated from MVC3 to MVC4, but I guess Im missed something. What's interesting is that it works for iPhone browser but not Androids (at least some of them).
It works fine in clean mvc4 project.
So i am not sure what im missing, i will go over mvc3>4 upgrade instructions again to see what I have missed. If i do not see anything, I will try implementation with 51devices or do clean MVC4 project.

UPDATE: Followed the upgrade instructions again, I do not see anything that I missed.
So I ended up implementing 51devices way, per these instructions:
http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/26/51Degrees-mobi-and-MVC4.aspx
android devices seem to trigger mobile display fine now.
The only update is to use:

```
`DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert`
```

instead of

```
 `DisplayModes.Modes.Insert`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your mobile browser is sending in the correct user agent strings, especially if you are using a mobile browser emulator.  I have had good luck with the new chrome user agent overriding in the console settings, and some plugins for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having Areas on your MVC application, you will need to modify the `_ViewStart.cshtml` inside each area.